# No funciona el envío de datos con POST con formulario de contacto en Django

Tags: django

He hecho un formulario de contacto con django pero no me funciona el envío de datos con POST.
He mirado que gmail acepte envío de información de terceros, pero no he sabido cómo hacerlo y tampoco sé si ese es el problema.

En settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER= "@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="contraseña"
```

> Aquí he quitado la dirección de correo y la contraseña para que no se muestre.

En form.py

```py
    from django import forms
    
    class FormularioContacto(forms.Form):
    
        
        nombre=forms.CharField(label="Nombre * ", required=True)
        email=forms.EmailField(label="Email * ", required=True)
        telefono=forms.CharField(label="Teléfono * ",required=True)
        asunto=forms.CharField(label="Asunto * ", required=True)
        Disponibilidad=forms.CharField(label="Disponibilidad horaria * ",required=True)
        mensaje=forms.CharField(label="Mensaje ", widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

views.py

```py
    from .forms import FormularioContacto
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    
    
    def contacto(request):
        formulario_contacto=FormularioContacto()
    
        if request.method=="POST":
            formulario_contacto=FormularioContacto(data=request.POST)
            if formulario_contacto.is_valid():
                nombre=request.POST.get("nombre")
                email=request.POST.get("email")
                telefono=request.POST.get("telefono")
                disponobilidad=request.POST.get("disponbilidad")
                asunto=request.POST.get("asunto")
                mensaje=request.POST.get("mensaje")
    
                email=EmailMessage("Mensaje desde web Arca de Gaia",
                "El cliente {} con el email {} escribe el siguiente mensaje:\n\n 
                 {}".format(nombre,email,telefono,disponobilidad,asunto,mensaje),
                "",["terapiaselarcadegaia@gmail.com"],reply_to=[email])
    
                try:
                    email.send()
    
                    return redirect("/contacto/?valido")
                
                except:
                    return redirect("/contacto/?novalido")
    
    
        return render(request,"arcaGaiaApp/contacto.html", 
        {'miFormulario':formulario_contacto})
```

contacto.html

```html
    {% block content %}
    
    <div class="contenedorFormulario">
    
        {% if "valido" in request.GET %}
          <p>Información enviada correctamente</p>
        {% endif%}
    
      <form id="form_contacto" action="" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <table>{{miFormulario.as_p}}</table>
          <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </form>
    
    </div>
    
    {% endblock%}
```

No sé cuál es el error por el que no se envía la información: cuando le doy al botón *enviar* me sale la excepción  ?novalido

Answer (score 0):

Estimado lo que sucede es que google a cambiado sus politias de acceso para las aplicaciones menos seguras y tienes que hacer una autentificacion de dos pasas primero y luego generar y crear una contraseña para tu aplicacion te recomienod ver este video ojo como referencia [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Etj_6yBeS6s)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, ya lo tengo resuelto.
Supongo que si pongo una dirección de correo distinta y una contraseña de un dominio no tendré este problema verdad?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).